# NFSClient issue on FreeBSD: "rpc.umntall: not found"

Tags: freebsd, nfs, nfsclient

We have a FreeBSD 8 server that hasn't been restarted since it got booted. It has been restarted now and we're trying to reconnect the NFS mount to it.

```
$ sudo /etc/rc.d/nfsclient start
NFS access cache time=60
rpc.umntall: not found
```

The obvious reason for the error `rpc.umntall: not found` is because the program doesn't exist on the computer.

Is there any other way to mount to a  NFS server that is connected to the network than using NFSClient. Or can I force the client to move past the part in the script that requires `rpc.umntall`?

I only ask because it was started before, and I'd be very surprised if we removed any programs from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpc.umntall` is installed as part of the base system, usually in `/usr/sbin/`.

If you take a look at the contents of `/etc/rc.d/nfsclient`, you'll find this:

```
unmount_all()
{
        # If /var/db/mounttab exists, some nfs-server has not been
        # successfully notified about a previous client shutdown.
        # If there is no /var/db/mounttab, we do nothing.
        if [ -f /var/db/mounttab ]; then
                rpc.umntall -k
        fi
}
```

A cheap work around would be to delete `/var/db/mounttab`.

However, if you want to fix the problem, you'll want to fix the missing `rpc.umntall`. Is it not in `/usr/sbin/`? If not, you could try to restore it from a published image, or you could attempt to build it from source. 
If it's somewhere else on the computer, you could try to find it using `find / | grep rcp.umntall`.

If it exists in `/usr/sbin`, but isn't working, then that would likely mean that something is wrong with the `PATH` variable being used by your rc subsystem. You could double check that by hardcoding the path to `rpc.umntall` right in the `/etc/rc.d/nfsclient` script.

Comment: Thanks! It's not in sbin/ I'm in a pickle. Server can't/shouldn't come offline - slightly custom distro of freebsd, and the find command did not return anything (I had tried that :P ) I appreciate it, I had seen unmount_all and was curious if there was a way to force it, without deleting the file. Or is there another command I could do? Ironically the only client in the mountdtab is the one I can't connect... Any command to *mount* that could bypass this without modifications?

Comment: Either way I'm going to accept your answer because I am likely going to modify the `/etc/rc.d/nfsclient` file since it is already not taking advantage of `unmntall`. :-)